# Terraform aws getting started issues

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, terraform

i'm running on last version of windows and i'm trying to use terraform for aws for the first time. I've created a free account everything is ready to work.

here is my test.tf

```
provider "aws" {
   access_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" // don't worry i change this
   secret_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" //  this too
   region = "eu-west-1" #Irlande
}

resource "aws_instance" "bastion" {
   ami = "ami-0d063c6b"
   instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

and when i terraform plan this nothing happen :

Any solution to this issue ?
Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: It just takes some time. What's output after that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you run with latest terraform.

Did you run `terraform init` first? If you use aws as provider, you should be fine to use s3 as backend

Take a look at [Terraform init usage](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/init.html)